# Best way check if one IP is in any range within a large array of ip ranges (PHP)

Tags: php, range, ip

I have a large number (1,000 or more) of IP ranges. I need to check each site visitor's IP against the various ranges.

My plan right now is to store the ranges as a single two-dimensional array, like such:

```
<?php $IP_ranges = array 
     (
     array("low_ip ","high_ip "),
     array("low_ip ","high_ip "),
     array("low_ip ","high_ip "),
     //etc
     ); ?>
```

So the first array might be 100.00.00.1 to 100.00.00.90.

Then I'd check if an IP is in any of the ranges by iterating through the array with a foreach loop, converting the IPs to numbers using ip2long(), and then check if the user's IP is in the range doing something like this:

```
if ($ip <= $high_ip && $low_ip <= $ip) {
   return true;
}
```

**My question is if this is the most efficient way of checking if a given ip is in any of the stored ranges?**

I'll have to do this once per visitor on a public site. It's not super high-traffic but I don't want to use up unnecessary resources.

Comment: What's the reason for this check?

Comment: It's a whitelist for protected content. Those with a whitelisted IP can see site content that is otherwise protected. But the content itself is too dynamic and spread out to manage this with, say, .htaccess.

Comment: The most efficient way to handle this is with bitwise operators using the address and the subnet.  I don't remember how to do bitwise operators in PHP off the top of my head, but I'm sure that's documented somewhere.